# PhoneGap Variables No Passing

Tags: cordova

I am writing an app in Phone Gap but I cannot get the variables to pass to my script using the Ajax post. The Ajax post works fine when I submit it like this “lon=51.02&lat=0.00&ap=1539”.
But when I try and add Phone Gap Variables to it like this “lon=” + PGLon + “&lat=”+ PGLat + “&ap=1539” I cannot get it to submit.

```
function onSuccess(position) {
    var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');

    div.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '             + position.coords.latitude  + '<br/>' +
                    'Longitude: '            + position.coords.longitude + '<br/>' +
                    'Altitude: '             + position.coords.altitude  + '<br/>' +
                    'Accuracy: '             + position.coords.accuracy  + '<br/>' +
                    'Altitude Accuracy: '    + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '<br/>' +
                    'Heading: '              + position.coords.heading   + '<br/>' +
                    'Speed: '                + position.coords.speed     + '<br/>';

    var PGLon =  'Longitude: '             + position.coords.longitude  + '';   
    var PFLat =  'Latitude: '             + position.coords.latitude  + '';         
}

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  cache: false,
  url: "http://MyWebSite.com/uppost.php",
  data: "lon=" + PGLon + "&lat="+ PGLat + "&ap=1539" ,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    alert('Success: The text is now stored in the database.');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    cache: false,
    url: "http://MyWebSite.com/uppost.php", 
    data: {"lon":  PGLon , "lat": PGLat , "ap":1539} , 
    dataType: "text", 
    success: function(data) { 
                alert('Success: The text is now stored in the database.'); },
    error: function(e){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
    }

  });
```